# RubyMine debug gem versions different from public gem versions

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubygems, rubymine

I am using RubyMine version 2021.1 on Mac OS (10.15.7, Catalina) and Ubuntu.

I am having difficulty getting the debugging gem installation to work with a custom Ruby that is outside of my rvm environment, and noticed that the debugging gems that RubyMine is trying to install on my behalf have versions different from the public ones:

| Gem | Latest Public Version | RubyMine Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| debase | 0.2.4.1 | 2.3.2 |
| ruby-debug-ide | 0.7.2 | 2.3.1 |

Why is this? Does RubyMine have its own proprietary versions of these gems?

Comment: Where do you see the "RubyMine Version"? In the UI or CLI? I don't see these gems under Preferences -> "Ruby SDK and Gems". So, I guess these are "non-bundle" gems?

Comment: debase 2.3.2 is a proprietary backend bundled with Ruby plugin or RubyMine. You may use opensource gem from rubygems by disabling 'use experimental debugger' setting.

Comment: I found the RubyMine version by looking in the gems of the rvm versions that were working fine, for example: `rvm 2.7.2; gem list debase`. Yes, they are not specified in Gemfile or the gemspec file.

Comment: I can't find the setting to disable "use experimental debugger". where can i find that? i'm using rubymine 2022.1.3

Comment: @JaredBeck Sorry for the delay; these gems are used by RubyMine across all projects, so they don't need to be configured per project, and it makes sense to me that they would not be listed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the gemspec, these gems have been "forked" by JetBrains and the RubyMine's come from their proprietary repos (https://github.com/JetBrains):
s.homepage = "https://github.com/JetBrains/debase".

Hence there are differences in versions.